# Prove that $f$ is a group isomorphism, where $f$ interchanges the primes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $G = \mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ be the multiplicative group of nonzero rational numbers. If $\alpha = p/q \in G$ where $(p,q) = 1$, let $f: G → G$ be the map which interchanges the primes $2$ and $3$ in the prime power factorization of $p$ and $q$ (so, for example, $f(2^43^57^113^2) = 3^42^57^113^2$ and $f(3/16) = f(3/2^4) = 2/3^4 = 2/81$), and $f$ is the identity on all rational numbers with numerators and denominators relatively prime to $2$ and to $3 $.

**a)** Prove that $f$ is a group isomorphism.

**Attempt:** let $x,y \in G$ and $x = 2^{a_1}3^{b_1}k_1j_1, y = 2^{a_2}3^{b_2}k_2j_2$. Then we need to show it is a group homomorphism.

Then $f(xy) = f((2^{a_1}3^{b_1}k_1j_1)(2^{a_2}3^{b_2}k_2j_2)) = f(2^{a_1 + a_2}3^{b_1 + b_2}k_1k_2j_1j_2) = 3^{a_1 + a_2}2^{b_1 + b_2}k_1k_2j_1j_2 = 3^{a_1}2^{b_1}k_1j_1(3^{a_2}2^{b_2}k_2j_2) = f(2^{a_1}3^{b_1}k_1j_1)f(2^{a_2}3^{b_2}k_2j_2) = f(x)f(y)$

So $f$ is a group homomorphism.

Now we need to show that it is a onto and injective function.

*onto:* it is onto since for every $ y = 2^{a_2}3^{b_2}k_2j_2 \in G$, there exists $x = 2^{a_1}3^{b_1}k_1j_1 \in G$ such that $y = f(x)$

*injective*: let $x_1 = 2^{a_1}3^{b_1}k_1s_1$ and $x_2 = 2^{a_2}3^{b_2}k_2s_2$.

Then $f(x_1) = f(x_2) $ $\Leftrightarrow$ $ f(2^{a_1}3^{b_1}k_1s_1) = f(2^{a_2}3^{b_2}k_2s_2)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $ 3^{a_1}2^{b_1}k_1j_1 = 3^{a_2}2^{b_2}k_2j_2 $.

I am kind of confused about proving it's a bijective function. Can someone please help me?

**b)** Prove that there are infinitely many isomorphisms of the group $G$ to itself.

**Attempt:** Generalize $f$ by $f(p^{a}q^{b}ks) = p^bq^aks$, where $p,q$ are any primes, that $f$ can interchanges them in the prime power factorizations.

Can someone please verify I am on the right track? Any suggestion or better approach would really help. Thank you!

Comment: I think surjectivity and injectivity is sufficient for functions in groups.

Comment: It may be useful to think $\mathbb{Q}^{\times} \cong \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \cdots $, one copy for each prime. That's what the  fundamental theorem of arithmetic says.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** To prove bijectivity (or injectivity/surjectivity) you can just calculate $f \circ f$. What is this?

For $(b)$ that is the right idea.

Comment: $f(f(x)) = x$ for any $x \in G$. So I can conclude that if it is an invertible function  then it is a bijective function. So $f$ is a group isomorphism

Comment: For part b) , would I also do the same thing (show it is a group homomorphism and a bijective function) but in the general defined function $f(p^aq^bks)=p^bq^aks$ for any primes? –

Answer (score 0):

This is looking good so far. To show surjectivity look at the cases,

I) $2|y$ and $3\nmid y$

II) $2\nmid y$ and $3|y$

III) $2|y$ and $3|y$

IV) $2\nmid y$ and $3\nmid y$.

Your approach to part b) is on target.